# How to use Apex Trigger on Attachment Objects to run a Callout on a PHP page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I would like to have an apex trigger fire any time an attachment object is added/deleted/modified.  When this trigger fires I would like to pass the attachment's parent ID through an apex class which will pass that ID to a PHP page on an external website (using GET is fine).

I do **not** have to display the PHP page, I just need the PHP page to run.  The php page just stores the ID in a MySQL database.  I also do **not** need to know what happened to the attachment (if it was added/deleted/modified).

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.  I have tried several different methods but I simply run into many errors that I can't figure out every time.  I don't think any of my attempts are worth sharing here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a callout working from within a trigger, you need to make one more step: An @future-Call.
That means, from within your trigger, you must collect all the IDs that were inserted/updated/deleted. Then, you must create a Class that implements a static void with the @future-Annotation (thus, this function is always executed asynchronously). Last, you call this function from the trigger and run your callout in the function.

```
trigger Attachment_AfterAll_Callout on Attachment (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    //collect your ids here
    //you might get away with just using ALL ids: ids = Trigger.newMap.keyset()
    //call @future Function
    WebserviceHandler.attachmentCall(ids);
}
```

In a class file:

```
public class WebserviceHandler {
     @future(callout=true)
     public static void attachmentCall(Set<Id> ids) {
         //make your WS Callout here. 
         //Note, this is not guaranteed to run inline with the trigger,
         //execution may be delayed!
     }
}
```

Please note that there are limits on how many @future Calls you may have running, so you should batch the execution.

Comment: The only problem I have is with deleting attachments I get the following error:
`attachMngr: execution of AfterDelete

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.attachMngr: line 5, column 1` Line 5 is: `ids = Trigger.newMap.keyset();` I tried changing after delete to before delete but that did not help either.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it with the following:
`if(Trigger.isInsert){
     ids = Trigger.newMap.keyset();
    } else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
     ids = Trigger.newMap.keyset();
    } else if(Trigger.isDelete ){
     ids = Trigger.oldMap.keyset();
    }`  Note the 'Trigger.old' instead of .new for the delete! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to test for that, you are right! `delete` is the only event on which you would want to use `Trigger.oldMap`, though.